# Detecting Selection Changes in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to find a way to detect changes in which column the user selected in a JTable.  I did some poking around and it appears that you need to somehow use a TableColumnModelListener in order to detect the changes, but that doesn't seem to fire an event when you change the column you have selected.

Comment: What program feature are you attempting to offer?

Comment: I have a JTable which essentially functions as a pictoral calendar at the moment.  I want to allow users to click on one of the cells in the Calendar and have all of their appointments on that date pop up in a separate JTable (a function that works when the calendar detects that the user has selected a different cell).

Comment: @Jonathon  Thanks for explaining that.  It often helps to state the goal, as well as whatever strategy you are applying to reach that goal, just in case there exists a far *better* strategy to achieve the actual goal.  At the very least, it will give people a context for answering. To be honest, I did not understand the precise nature of this problem until you added the goal.  Stating the goal also helps satisfy people's curiosity.  ;)

Comment: sounds a bit fishy - you really get no notification in your TableColumnModelListener? It has a method columnSelectionChanged which should have the same notification behaviour as hooking into the listSelectionModel which internally backs the selection state.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add a `ListSelectionListener` instead. That will capture selection events.  Here are some Swing tutorials that go further in depth:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection

Comment: I already have a listselectionlistener in place, and it works wonders when going from row 2 column 3 to row 3 column 3.  However, much like the demos there, it doesn't fire off an event when you change selections your selection from row 2 column 3 to row 2 column 2, making it impossible to detect the change.

Comment: In that case you need two listselectionlisteners.  One added to the column model just like this example: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#SimpleTableSelectionDemo

Comment: Belated thanks a bunch.  I couldn't find that site in all of my searching and it was exactly what I was looking for.  Perhaps I need to level my googling skills :\

Answer (score 2):

From what I read, I think you need to add a MouseListener to your table, which for example in mouseClicked will get the row and column using the following code, below:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {   
       Point pnt = evt.getPoint();
       int row = table.rowAtPoint(pnt);
       int col = table.columnAtPoint(pnt);
    }
}
```

It should work great for you I have used similar thing myself before.
BTW it look similar to the problem I found on coderanch, link:
 http://www.coderanch.com/t/332737/GUI/java/detect-single-click-any-cell

Good luck, Boro

Comment: no - the requirement is detect changes in "selected" column. That's a high-level (aka: semantic) state which can be changed by a multitude of low-level events (like mouse, keyboard, speech.. input). As a general rule, always go for the highest level of abstraction available.

Answer (score 0):

If by "change" you mean changing the value of a cell then you can use an [AbstractTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) and implement the **fireTableCellUpdated** method

Comment: No, I'm thinking of when the user clicks on a different cell, not when they are changing a value.  The data within the table cannot be edited.